# Call modal controller inside a navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, modalviewcontroller, navigationcontroller

I would like to call a `modal view controller` from a controller inside a `navigation controller`..

I should do

```
[self presentModalViewController:<#(UIViewController *)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#>];
```

OR

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:<#(UIViewController *)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#>];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use whichever one makes you happy, though calling it on the navigation controller seems to be a bit more in line with the overall flow of the app.

Answer (score -1):

Both ways are ok.You can use any one .